# mongodb complex collection filtering based on $gt

Tags: mongodb, filter, pymongo

I have a MongoDB collection that has document in the following format:

```
result of MyCollection.find({"_id": "20141029"})

{
    "_id" : "20141029", 
    "portfolio_returns" : [
        {       
            "data" : [
                {
                    "report" : {
                        "open" : {
                            "returns_rs" : 398.8
                        },
                        "both" : {
                            "returns_rs" : 1054.800
                        }
                    },
                    "portfolio" : "Mystocks"
                }
            ],
            "user" : "mzmmohideen@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "data" : [
                {
                    "report" : {
                        "open" : {
                            "returns_rs" : 5000
                        },
                        "both" : {
                            "returns_rs" : 5500
                        }
                    },
                    "portfolio" : "pff"
                }
            ],
            "user" : "mani@ithoughtz.com"
        }
    ],

'portfolio_stock_gain_or_loss': [
        {
            "data" : [
                {
                    "portfolio" : "gm",
                    "stocks" : [ ]
                }
            ],
            "user" : "moorthy.gm@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "data" : [
                {
                    "portfolio" : "Mystocks",
                    "stocks" : [
                        {
                            "open" : {
                                "returns_rs" : 9144
                            },
                            "scripcode" : "532540",
                            "both" : {
                                "returns_rs" : 9426.75
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "open" : {
                                "returns_rs" : 254.80
                            },
                            "scripcode" : "500790",
                            "both" : {
                                "returns_rs" : 254.80
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "user" : "mzmmohideen@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "data" : [
                {
                    "portfolio" : "pff",
                    "stocks" : [
                        {
                            "open" : {
                                "returns_rs" : 4000
                            },
                            "scripcode" : "500790",
                            "both" : {
                                "returns_rs" : 8500
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "open" : {
                                "returns_rs" : 0
                            },
                            "scripcode" : "533151",
                            "both" : {
                                "returns_rs" : 0
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "user" : "mani@ithoughtz.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

My question is how can I filter out data from this doccument that have "portfolio_stock_gain_or_loss.data.stocks.open.returns_rs" greater than 1000 using pymongo.

expecting out put is

```
{
    "_id" : "20141029", 

'portfolio_stock_gain_or_loss': [

        {
            "data" : [
                {
                    "portfolio" : "Mystocks",
                    "stocks" : [
                        {
                            "open" : {
                                "returns_rs" : 9144
                            },
                            "scripcode" : "532540",
                            "both" : {
                                "returns_rs" : 9426.75
                            }
                        }


                    ]
                }
            ],
            "user" : "mzmmohideen@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "data" : [
                {
                    "portfolio" : "pff",
                    "stocks" : [
                        {
                            "open" : {
                                "returns_rs" : 4000
                            },
                            "scripcode" : "500790",
                            "both" : {
                                "returns_rs" : 8500
                            }
                        },

                    ]
                }
            ],
            "user" : "mani@ithoughtz.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

Any ideas how I can do this on existing data or should I need to change the format?

Many thanks

Comment: If you want to take the existing document and only return the elements of the nested array that are <= 1000, you will need to do the filtering client-side as there is no way to do that in MongoDB.

Answer (score 2):

Hi your mongo documents are too nested I think if possible you should restructure your mongo documents. Otherwise if you want to continue with same documents then mongo aggregation help full for solving your problem. I write following mongo aggregation I think it solves your problem

```
    db.MyCollection.aggregate([ 
                              {"$unwind":"$portfolio_stock_gain_or_loss"}, 
                              {"$unwind":"$portfolio_stock_gain_or_loss.data"}, 
                              {"$unwind":"$portfolio_stock_gain_or_loss.data.stocks"},
                              {"$project":{"openStock":"$portfolio_stock_gain_or_loss.data.stocks.open","data":"$portfolio_stock_gain_or_loss.data"}},
                              {"$match": {"openStock.returns_rs":{"$gt":1000}}} ]).pretty()
```